# Problems using scrapy fetch

Tags: python, scrapy, fetch

EDIT:

Hi, I learn some scrapy from a YouTube tutorial.
I used this commands (like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4jtkzHhLzY):

```
> scrapy startproject whiskyscraper
> cd whiskyscraper
> tree
.
├── scrapy.cfg
└── whiskyscraper
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── middlewares.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │   └── settings.cpython-310.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    └── spiders
        ├── __init__.py
        └── __pycache__
            └── __init__.cpython-310.pyc

> scrapy shell
> fetch('https://kwejk.pl/')
```

...and after fetch() i got this problem:

```
>>> fetch('https://kwejk.pl/')
2023-01-22 11:07:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kwejk.pl/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-01-22 11:07:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kwejk.pl/> (referer: None)
2023-01-22 11:07:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://kwejk.pl/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/poppap/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/poppap/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 285, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "/home/poppap/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 272, in deferred_from_coro
    event_loop = get_asyncio_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (start)'.
```

I use PyCharm venv, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and don't know how to fix this error.

(Sorry for the first version of this post - I am new here)

Comment: Please post your code and a link to the tutorial your code is based on. Also, please include error message as text and not as a link to an image.

Comment: ok, ok, done...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using Scrapy version 2.7.1. Please inform me, if you are using a different version. You can check that using `scrapy version` command in your terminal.

It seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5742) with Scrapy 2.7.1, which probably will be fixed in future versions. For now, you can remediate that by installing one of previous versions, for example `pip install scrapy==2.7.0` instead of just `pip install scrapy`.

The tutorial you are following seems to be using scrapy==2.4.1 so in order to recreate that you could be running `pip install scrapy==2.4.1`. I don't see which Python version the tutorial is using, so it's hard to recreate the tutorial completely.

Comment: You are right, I have 2.7.1 and the tutorial is from two years ago. I tried a newer tutorial and it looks a bit different now and it seems to be working. Thanks for getting me on the right track!